# Velocity #parse but assign it to a variable

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

Say you have a standard template with included (parsed) header, body, footer templates.

In the body template a variable like $subject is defined and you want that also displayed in the header template.

In some other template languages like HTML::Mason(perl based) you would evaluate the body template first to pick up the $subject variable but store it's output temporarily in a variable so your final output could end up in the correct order (header, body, footer)

In velocity it would look something like

set ($body=#parse("body.vm"))

parse("header.vm")

${body}

parse("footer.vm")

This however doesn't seem to work,  any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Either of the two solutions above would work.  The VelocityLayoutServlet solution requires an extra package (also from Velocity) called Velocity Tools.  I'm partial to this approach (and variants) myself.

A third method is simply to put the #parse within quotes:

```
set ($body="#parse('body.vm')")
```

Within a #set, anything in double quotes is evaluated.  Strings within single quotes are passed in literally.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [VelocityLayoutServlet](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/view/layoutservlet.html) which is part of [VelocityTools](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/index.html).

This allows you to define a layout for your application -- let's call it `application.vm` -- in which you can parse in headers, footers etc and declare where the main body content is placed using the `screen_content` declaration, e.g:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$subject</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  #parse("header.vm") 
  $screen_content
  #parse("footer.vm") 
  </body>
</html>
```

`VelocityLayoutServlet` will evalulate the templates (and, hence, variables) before rendering which allows you to set a `$subject` variable in your body template, e.g:

```
#set($subject = "My Subject")
<div id="content">
</div>
```

More detailed information can be found [in the Velocity documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/view/layoutservlet.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a Velocity variable named `$subject` interpolated into the `header.vm` and the `body.vm` templates. Right now, the variable is defined in the `body.vm` template, so you cannot refer to it in the earlier template `header.vm`.

Why don't you abstract out the definition of $subject into its own template snippet, called `globals.vm` say, then include that in the top-level template. So you'd have:

```
#parse("globals.vm")
#parse("header.vm")
#parse("body.vm")
#parse("footer.vm")
```